# Autokey phrase for special character

Tags: hotkeys

I use special characters like é or ü regularly, and have a "phrase" for each in Autokey.
Example: to get é I have to press CTRL+Shift+E simulutaneously. For ü it is CTRL+Shift+U.

But this does not work for ö, ş, ğ. Any suggestion as to how to get these to work with a simple key combination in Autokey?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question seems to be about PC administration topic, not about a programming problem or a software algorithm. If so, please go to superuser.com. If not, better describe the problem and set appropriate tags. It certainly has nothing to do with *character-encoding*.

Comment: No, it has absolutely nothing to do with admin. When I type a text, whether in one of my documents or e.g. on a forum, I use those special character letters, they are letters used in different languages such as French, German, Turkish. So, rather thanopening a character map and copy/pasting those, I want to use a keyboard key combination to reproduce them. I changed the tag.

Comment: And which aspect of your problem is a programming or algorithmic problem?

Comment: The problem is that in the Autokey box for a phrase I can just put "é" and activate the key combination CTRL+Shift+E, which means that if I want to type an "é" in my text I can just press that key combination. If, I put ö (an "o" with 2 dots) in the Autokey phrase box and activate.g. CTRL+Shift+O, it does not work. Why not, and how can I overcome this? Would a script be more appropriate for the ö (an "o" with 2 dots)?

Comment: Note: Autokey is based on Python an so are the scripts it can run.